# Regex: Look for a specific word after the first backslash occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I'm wanting to use regex to look for the word "bacon" after the first "/" occurrence.

For example:

Should return true:

```
console.log('1 - ', myRegexFunction('www.bacondelivery.com/weekly-bacon-delivery/'));
console.log('2 - ', myRegexFunction('www.bacondelivery.com/daily-bacon-delivery/'));
console.log('3 - ', myRegexFunction('www.bacondelivery.com/bacon-of-the-month-club/'));
```

Should return false:

```
console.log('4 - ', myRegexFunction('www.bacondelivery.com/'));
console.log('5 - ', myRegexFunction('www.bacondelivery.com/?some_param'));
console.log('6 - ', myRegexFunction('www.bacondelivery.com/about/'));
console.log('7 - ', myRegexFunction('www.bacondelivery.com/contact-us/'));
```

Here's what I currently have:

```
function myRegexFunction(url) {
  var regex = new RegExp("^([a-z0-9]{5,})$");
  if (regex.test(url)) {
      return true;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex for this:

```bash
^[^\/]+\/[^\/]*\bbacon\b.*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WiARoM/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `[^\/]+`: Match 1 or more of any character that is not a `/`
- `\/`: Match a `/`
- `[^\/]*`: Match 0 or more of any character that is not a `/`
- `\bbacon\b`: Match complete word `bacon`
- `.*`: Match remaining text on this line

**Code:**

```js
function myRegexFunction(url) {
  const regex = /^[^\/]+\/[^\/]*\bbacon\b.*/;
  return regex.test(url);
}

console.log('1 - ', myRegexFunction('www.bacondelivery.com/weekly-bacon-delivery/'));

console.log('2 - ', myRegexFunction('www.bacondelivery.com/daily-bacon-delivery/'));
console.log('3 - ', myRegexFunction('www.bacondelivery.com/bacon-of-the-month-club/'));

console.log('4 - ', myRegexFunction('www.bacondelivery.com/'));
console.log('5 - ', myRegexFunction('www.bacondelivery.com/?some_param'));
console.log('6 - ', myRegexFunction('www.bacondelivery.com/about/'));
console.log('7 - ', myRegexFunction('www.bacondelivery.com/contact-us/'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following regex:

```
\/.*\bbacon\b
```

If you get a match, it means you have that word in your url. If you need to match it case-insentitively, then you can use the 'i' modifier.

Regex Explanation:

- `\/`: a slash
- `.*`: any character
- `\bbacon\b`: your hotword between word boundaries

Check the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/B1ipCX/1).

---

**EDIT**: If you want to match your bacon "*word*" specifically after the first occurrence, check anubhava's answer.

Comment: I think this will match `bacon` anywhere after a `/` not just after first `/` and before second `/` (hope I am interpreting question correctly)

Comment: Actually there's some freedom of interpretation in writing "*after the first "/" occurrence*". Better having a complete answer than a partial one. Thanks @anubhava

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a simple one : `const regex = /\/.*(bacon)/`

```js
function myRegexFunction(url) {
  var regex = /\/.*(bacon)/;
  if (regex.test(url)) {
      return true;
  } else {
      return false;
  }
}
```

- `\/` to match after a `/`
- `.*` 0 to n character
- `(bacon)` your pattern (parenthesis are optional)

Be aware it will not work if your link is `http://baconurl/…`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
/\/.*bacon/
```